# How sql numeric db columns works with numeric string values

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a question related to SQL.

I am recently coding an application, where sql query is generated dynamically based on user's inputs from UI. Interestingly list of values passed from UI were all of strings. I was told to add support of numeric values. But  what I noticed that passing `numeric string value` to numeric field also works.

for example:

```
Select * from employee where id = 36815
```

and

```
Select * from employee where id = "36815"
```

My question is why second query work. Even if I change `=` operator to `<` or `>` , it still works. I want to know why it works and should we support it as it is. What can be disadvantages of using numeric string fields for numeric db columns.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Values in databases have types.  And, you should learn not to mix types in expressions -- particularly in `where` and `on` clauses -- because such mixing can confuse the optimizer.

What is happening in your expression?  The SQL compiler is seeing something like:

```
where <number> = <string>
```

By the rules of SQL, it says that the string needs to be converted to a number.  MySQL does this by converting leading digits.  So the result is something like:

```
where <number> = cast(string as int)
```

(although non-integers are allowed).

Note that this is not based on the string being a constant.  Only on the type of the columns.  So, if the expression were:

```
where stringcol = 5
```

Then `stringcol` would be converted to a number.

Comment: The rules applied in MySQL are completely described in [Type Conversion in Expression Evaluation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/type-conversion.html).

Comment: any disadvantage of going with second query? If we know type conversions are implicit.

Comment: @Sagar . . . Yes.  Mixing types can confuse the optimizer and cause queries to run slower.  It can also cause unexpected matches.  For instance `1 = '1x'` evaluates to true, not false.